# How do I get the shell on the screen?

Tags: command-line, terminal, gnome, virtualbox

I'm completely new to Linux. I've googled but I can't find the keyboard shortcut command for this anywhere. I tried Ctrl-Alt-F3 from the graphical desktop, but it takes me to a login screen. Back on the desktop, I went to open bash through the GUI but it did nothing at all. This is so frustrating.

I'm running "Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 alias squeeze" inside VirtualBox for Windows, from here, and it has two sets of login details: http://virtualboxes.org/images/debian/

Also: I remember seeing someone pull-up the shell over a graphical desktop, almost like Alt-tabbing in Windows but with the text overlaid on the desktop with a semi-transparent black background. Is this possible for Debian?

Comment: ctrl+alt+t for terminal perhaps?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might want to use Debian Wheezy instead -- Squeeze is getting pretty long in the tooth now.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It appears to me that you are asking several questions within this question. The Q&A format used by Unix & Linux and Stack Exchange works best when each question deals only with one specific issue, the answer to which can be judged on its technical merits. Please [edit] your question such that it asks only a single question which can be answered preferably within a few paragraphs. You may [ask several questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you have more than one question you want answered. As it stands this question may be at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that under VirtualBox (and especially in Windows) the usual short-cuts doesn't work quite right - after all, both VB and Windows tries to "hijack" the keys Debian wants.

Inside X under Linux, you'd *usually* use CTRL-ALT-F1~Fn to switch between VTs... but in VB, you must use the "Host-Key" (usually the right-side CTRL-key) and the F1~Fn keys.

So *hold down* the right CTRL (host) and press F1, and you should get the 1st VT... to return to X, do the same, but use F7 or F8 instead.

Comment: My understanding is that Ctrl+Alt+F3 did work for them, as they talk about seeing "a login screen". I think they might prefer using a normal X-based emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Most X desktop environments in common use bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to a "Run" dialog by default.

So try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and if that brings up a run dialog of some kind, start a *terminal*, not the shell. (The shell will simply exit immediately because there is nothing to read commands from.) Depending on what is installed you can try `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `rxvt` and a few others. `xterm` is almost guaranteed to be available but is not particularly fancy; however, it certainly will get you to a shell prompt.

Also, like Flup pointed out in a comment, Squeeze is getting pretty old. The current release is Wheezy, also known as Debian 7.x, [released in May 2013](https://www.debian.org/News/2013/20130504), whereas [Squeeze was originally released in February 2011](https://www.debian.org/News/2011/20110205a) and is currently termed oldstable, which basically means it is in maintenance-only mode. (The upcoming release, Jessie, is [slated to be frozen in early November 2014](https://release.debian.org/jessie/freeze_policy.html).) Hence, you may want to consider upgrading.